# Is there a way to set the DPI of a QPicture?

Tags: c++, qt, printing, pyqt

Is there a way to set the DPI of a `QPicture`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. At least, not in a convenient way. The only approach I can think of is to scale the QPainter used to create the QPicture. If you are painting the picture using QPainter operations, as opposed to just setting it on a QLabel, you could possibly scale that QPainter instead.

Comment: This screws up to painted text.

Comment: Do you mean that the scaled fonts look worse than fonts with properly chosen font sizes?